# Join SQL server tables without a unique identifier and duplicate data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm relatively inexperienced in SQL and could use some help beyond the usual SELECT and JOIN.

**The Problem**

Suppose you have 2 tables you wish to join in Microsoft SQL, however they are missing a unique identifier so duplicates entries are incorrectly generated. I've created an example SQLfiddle to try and demonstrate using a small subset of the full database schema **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/df3fc**.

One table has a list of measurement steps taken for 2 systems, identified by their serial. These measurement steps can contain multiple pieces of data, which are contained in the second table. This would not normally be an issue but, as in the sqlfiddle example for serial=1004, sometimes the same data may be retaken as part of a rework. When I then query, each piece of rework data gets joined to each step, duplicating data. The select query:

```
SELECT my_measurement_steps.id AS steps_id, my_measurement_steps.serial, my_measurement_data.id AS data_id, my_measurement_data.my_data, my_measurement_data.measurementid, my_measurement_steps.date
FROM my_measurement_steps INNER JOIN
      my_measurement_data ON my_measurement_steps.serial = my_measurement_data.serial AND
        my_measurement_steps.measurementid = my_measurement_data.measurementid
```

**Desired Output**

| steps_id | serial | data_id | my_data | measurementid | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 1004 | 36 | 0.9496555 | 33 | 2021-10-12 07:55:58.100 |
| 14 | 1004 | 35 | -0.03252285 | 11 | 2021-10-07 07:56:31.530 |
| 14 | 1004 | 34 | -0.0003081787 | 11 | 2021-10-07 07:56:31.530 |
| 13 | 1004 | 33 | -0.01728721 | 10 | 2021-10-07 07:56:31.530 |
| 13 | 1004 | 32 | -0.1996608 | 10 | 2021-10-07 07:56:31.530 |
| 12 | 1004 | 31 | 0.003044653 | 9 | 2021-10-07 07:24:49.500 |
| 12 | 1004 | 30 | 0.002392432 | 9 | 2021-10-07 07:24:49.500 |
| 11 | 1004 | 29 | 1.012242 | 8 | 2021-10-07 07:24:30.720 |
| 11 | 1004 | 28 | 1.003897 | 8 | 2021-10-07 07:24:30.720 |
| 11 | 1004 | 27 | 0.9917302 | 8 | 2021-10-07 07:24:30.720 |
| 11 | 1004 | 26 | -0.002975781 | 8 | 2021-10-07 07:24:30.720 |
| 11 | 1004 | 25 | -0.002746948 | 8 | 2021-10-07 07:24:30.720 |
| 10 | 1004 | 24 | 0.9695401 | 33 | 2021-10-05 11:37:51.430 |
| 9 | 1005 | 23 | 0.9731983 | 33 | 2021-10-05 08:00:10.490 |
| 8 | 1005 | 22 | 0.01013499 | 11 | 2021-10-01 07:12:07.470 |
| 8 | 1005 | 21 | -0.007311231 | 11 | 2021-10-01 07:12:07.470 |
| 7 | 1005 | 20 | -0.0003634033 | 10 | 2021-10-01 07:12:07.470 |
| 7 | 1005 | 19 | -0.2021408 | 10 | 2021-10-01 07:12:07.470 |
| 6 | 1005 | 18 | -0.002507007 | 9 | 2021-09-30 13:00:57.260 |
| 6 | 1005 | 17 | 0.001181299 | 9 | 2021-09-30 13:00:57.260 |
| 5 | 1005 | 16 | 1.007857 | 8 | 2021-09-30 12:39:50.280 |
| 5 | 1005 | 15 | 1.000333 | 8 | 2021-09-30 12:39:50.280 |
| 5 | 1005 | 14 | 0.9913442 | 8 | 2021-09-30 12:39:50.280 |
| 5 | 1005 | 13 | 0.002449243 | 8 | 2021-09-30 12:39:50.280 |
| 5 | 1005 | 12 | -0.002550488 | 8 | 2021-09-30 12:39:50.280 |
| 4 | 1004 | 11 | -0.02970417 | 11 | 2021-09-30 06:57:33.160 |
| 4 | 1004 | 10 | -0.0007542603 | 11 | 2021-09-30 06:57:33.160 |
| 3 | 1004 | 9 | -0.005267761 | 10 | 2021-09-30 06:57:33.160 |
| 3 | 1004 | 8 | -0.2038888 | 10 | 2021-09-30 06:57:33.160 |
| 2 | 1004 | 7 | -0.007525305 | 9 | 2021-09-30 06:56:59.060 |
| 2 | 1004 | 6 | -0.004998779 | 9 | 2021-09-30 06:56:59.060 |
| 1 | 1004 | 5 | 0.9935537 | 8 | 2021-09-29 12:34:08.090 |
| 1 | 1004 | 4 | 0.9952038 | 8 | 2021-09-29 12:34:08.090 |
| 1 | 1004 | 3 | 0.9978707 | 8 | 2021-09-29 12:34:08.090 |
| 1 | 1004 | 2 | -0.0006630127 | 8 | 2021-09-29 12:34:08.090 |
| 1 | 1004 | 1 | 0.0002386719 | 8 | 2021-09-29 12:34:08.090 |

---

I'm unsure how to achieve the desired output given the repeating data. Also for some serials there can be more than 1 repeat as shown in the example.

Happy to provide any extra information required.

Many Thanks.

---

**Code to Generate Tables**

```
create table my_measurement_steps(id int, serial int, measurementid int, date datetime);
create table my_measurement_data(id int, serial int, my_data float(7), measurementid int);

insert into my_measurement_steps values 
(1,1004,8,'2021-09-29 12:34:08.090'),
(2,1004,9,'2021-09-30 06:56:59.060'),
(3,1004,10,'2021-09-30 06:57:33.160'),
(4,1004,11,'2021-09-30 06:57:33.160'),
(5,1005,8,'2021-09-30 12:39:50.280'),
(6,1005,9,'2021-09-30 13:00:57.260'),
(7,1005,10,'2021-10-01 07:12:07.470'),
(8,1005,11,'2021-10-01 07:12:07.470'),
(9,1004,33,'2021-10-05 08:00:10.490'),
(10,1005,33,'2021-10-05 11:37:51.430'),
(11,1004,8,'2021-10-07 07:24:30.720'),
(12,1004,9,'2021-10-07 07:24:49.500'),
(13,1004,10,'2021-10-07 07:56:31.530'),
(14,1004,11,'2021-10-07 07:56:31.530'),
(15,1004,33,'2021-10-12 07:55:58.100');

insert into my_measurement_data values 
(1,1004,0.0002386719,8),
(2,1004,-0.0006630127,8),
(3,1004,0.9978707,8),
(4,1004,0.9952038,8),
(5,1004,0.9935537,8),
(6,1004,-0.004998779,9),
(7,1004,-0.007525305,9),
(8,1004,-0.2038888,10),
(9,1004,-0.005267761,10),
(10,1004,-0.0007542603,11),
(11,1004,-0.02970417,11),
(12,1005,-0.002550488,8),
(13,1005,0.002449243,8),
(14,1005,0.9913442,8),
(15,1005,1.000333,8),
(16,1005,1.007857,8),
(17,1005,0.001181299,9),
(18,1005,-0.002507007,9),
(19,1005,-0.2021408,10),
(20,1005,-0.0003634033,10),
(21,1005,-0.007311231,11),
(22,1005,0.01013499,11),
(23,1004,0.9695401,33),
(24,1005,0.9731983,33),
(25,1004,-0.002746948,8),
(26,1004,-0.002975781,8),
(27,1004,0.9917302,8),
(28,1004,1.003897,8),
(29,1004,1.012242,8),
(30,1004,0.002392432,9),
(31,1004,0.003044653,9),
(32,1004,-0.1996608,10),
(33,1004,-0.01728721,10),
(34,1004,-0.0003081787,11),
(35,1004,-0.03252285,11),
(36,1004,0.9496555,33);
```

**Edits**
Added datestamp to measurement step table - sqlfiddle not working so can't update.

All tables now updated and sqlfiddle

Removed section and added desired output

Comment: Would it be easier to understand if you can mention what is your actual required output?

Comment: @groovy_guy Very good idea. I've removed a section and added a table showing my desired output. Thanks!

Comment: So, how do you tell which data row belongs to which step row? Same serial, same measurement ID and ____? If both tables had a date, we could compare that, but as only the steps table has one, what column to take into consideration? To me it looks like the data model is flawed and the necessary information just isn't there.

Comment: You're right, the data model is incomplete in this regard. The only reason I know how the rows should be joined is that the data is entered chronologically into both tables. For example, the first 5 rows in the data table, which have the measurementid=8 and serial=1004, join to the 1st entry for those same criteria in the steps table. The rows 25-29 should join to the 2nd entry in the steps table. I was hoping I could create temporary tables with counters for those 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc in the select query, and then join on serial, measurementid and counter [example](https://imgur.com/a/BP1RosB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to detect blocks of rows belonging together.

When sorting `my_measurement_steps` we see that serial/measurementid 1004/8 occurs twice for instance, once in row #1 and then again in row #11.

When sorting `my_measurement_data` we see about the same thing. The serial/measurementid 1004/8 occurs in two blocks, once in rows #1-5 and then again in rows #25-29.

You want to join the serial/measurementid's nth occurence in `my_measurement_steps` with its nth occurrence in `my_measurement_data`.

The detection of such blocks is called a gaps and islands problem. This can be done with two concurrent row counts.

```
with data_groups_found as
(
  select
    my_measurement_data.*,
    row_number() over (order by id) -
    row_number() over (partition by serial, measurementid order by id) as grp
  from my_measurement_data
)
, data_groups_numbered as
(
  select
    data_groups_found.*,
    dense_rank() over (partition by serial, measurementid order by grp) as grp_id
  from data_groups_found
)
, steps_numbered as
(
  select
    my_measurement_steps.*,
    row_number() over (partition by serial, measurementid order by id) as grp_id
  from my_measurement_steps
)
select *
from steps_numbered s
left join data_groups_numbered d
            on d.serial = s.serial
           and d.measurementid = s.measurementid
           and d.grp_id = s.grp_id
order by s.id, d.id;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/df3fc/6

Comment: That's amazing, thank you so much for taking the time to help with my problem. From looking at other similar questions I thought answer may lie with row numbers, partitions etc, but no way I'd have got it without your help. I'm going to spend some time looking over your query so I understand what each section is doing and also study these 'gaps and islands' in data. Anyway, thanks again so much!